# JAX-RS: "RESTEASY002005: Failed executing GET org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, resteasy

I have created a simple service that enables me to listen to incoming REST requests and then perform a task and return the output of the task back to the caller as a custom object (MyObject).

This service runs perfectly fine while I execute it from IntelliJ [i am assuming the jaxrs jar are being loaded from InteliJ's internal repository] but fails when i execute the jar from command line. The exception is as follows:

```
[ERROR] RESTEASY002005: Failed executing GET /myapp/getVal
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.myproject.model.MyObject of media type: application/json
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$2(ServerResponseWriter.java:104) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:398) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:205) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:82) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:56) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:528) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:459) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:867) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) ~[myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
```

My code snippets are as follows:

**parent pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My Application</name>
  <description>My Application</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.agent.jar>${basedir}/target/jacoco-jars/jacocoagent.jar</sonar.jacoco.agent.jar>
    <jacoco.reports.unit.dir>${basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/unit</jacoco.reports.unit.dir>
    <jacoco.reports.it.dir>${basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/it</jacoco.reports.it.dir>
    <coverage.reports.dir>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports</coverage.reports.dir>
    <sonar.dynamic>reuseReports</sonar.dynamic>
    <guice.version>4.1.0</guice.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jetty.version>9.4.14.v20181114</jetty.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.6.2.Final</resteasy.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>
  <scm>
    <!-- My scm -->
  </scm>
  <repositories>
    <!-- My repositories -->
  </repositories>
  <modules>
    <module>myChild</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
        <version>${guice.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <finalName>myapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.myproject.main.mainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
          <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding} ${argLine}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**My child pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myChildApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myChildApp</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**My REST API code is a follows:**

```
@Path("/myapp")
@Singleton
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/getVal")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyObject getVal(@QueryParam("id") @NonNull String id) throws Exception {
        try {
            return getMyObjData(id);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have gone through a couple of links with similar issues but none helped me. For example:

[RestEasy: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089781/resteasy-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-type-java-uti)

[GET request fails with JAX-RS: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833220/get-request-fails-with-jax-rs-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-obj)

[simple example using resteasy-jaxrs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807266/simple-example-using-resteasy-jaxrs-not-working)

Based on my debugging with IntelliJ and by running the jar on command line, it appears to me that the jar I am trying to build does not have the dependency of jaxrs (if I am not mistaken) even though I have added them onto my pom. I therefore, am unsure how to proceed with this issue. Can someone help me out with this?

**Update:**

As per the comment I have updated my parent and child pom as below:

**Parent pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My Application</name>
  <description>My Application</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.agent.jar>${basedir}/target/jacoco-jars/jacocoagent.jar</sonar.jacoco.agent.jar>
    <jacoco.reports.unit.dir>${basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/unit</jacoco.reports.unit.dir>
    <jacoco.reports.it.dir>${basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/it</jacoco.reports.it.dir>
    <coverage.reports.dir>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports</coverage.reports.dir>
    <sonar.dynamic>reuseReports</sonar.dynamic>
    <guice.version>4.1.0</guice.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jetty.version>9.4.14.v20181114</jetty.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.6.2.Final</resteasy.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>
  <scm>
    <!-- My scm -->
  </scm>
  <repositories>
    <!-- My repositories -->
  </repositories>
  <modules>
    <module>myChild</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
        <version>${guice.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
          <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
          <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Child pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myChildApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myChildApp</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.myproject.main.mainClass</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Even after the above set of changes, I still see the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of debugging, I was able to find where the issue was. As can be seen in the pom files above, I am making use of Google Guice for DI.
While using Guice, we need to bind JacksonProvider as shown below:

**bind(JacksonJsonProvider.class)**

The reason why it was working for me on my IDE was because the IDE was loading the necessary dependency from its local repository (classpath).

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This will fix _this_ issue but you are missing more providers that should be auto registered, that aren’t. This was mentioned in the post I linked to.

Comment: Your answer also does not explain why it works in your IDE but not from the command line.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I have updated the comment as per the suggestion above.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha all other providers are in place except for JacksonJsonProvider. I was looking at the wrong place all along.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is similar to [this one with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36687312/2587435) where the services files (used to autoregister providers) are excluded from the fat jar built with the `maven-assembly-plugin`. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36687730/2587435) is to use the `maven-shade-plugin`, which has a transformer to concatenate the contents of all the services files into one file for the one single uber jar.

Comment: @ Paul Samsotha, appreciate your response. As per your comments, I have updated my parent and child pom (have updated it above). Yet, I am still facing the same issue. Could you have a look (at the build section of parent and child pom) and let me know if I have deviated in any way from your original comment?

Comment: @mang4521 you’re missing the Services transformer. You only added the manifest transformer. The services one is the main one that you need